# How to prevent battery saving when power cord is plugged out (TC52)

Tags: battery-saver

Trying to run a CPU intensive application on TC52 without power cord connected has this unwanted behavior of turning down the frequency of the CPU(s) after just a few seconds of activity. With charging cable connected, the CPU stays in the fast operation mode.

Is there any mechanism to try to convince the OS (Android 11) that no battery optimisation should happen in this case? (One would assume, that on low battery charging level, like < 20% one would like to enable this feature, but no on fully charged device). The Battery Management settings seem to have no effect.